# jQuery each #anchor do something

Tags: jquery, each

Need to know how to target each #anchor link to change an image on hover. Currently I am targeting one by one, do I need to wrap this in a each loop function?

Thanks in advance.

```
var originalpath = $('#fulltraceswap img').attr('src');
var root = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/home/";
//1
$("#fulltracerow .edgtf-iwt-title a[href='#aftermarketimage']").hover(
function(){       

    var path = root+"wp-content/uploads/2018/06/";
    var linkIndex = $(this).attr("href");
    linkIndex = linkIndex.replace('#', '');

    $('#fulltraceswap img').attr('src', path+linkIndex+".jpg");
    $('#fulltraceswap img').attr('srcset', path+linkIndex+".jpg");
},
function(){

    $('#fulltraceswap img').attr('src', originalpath);
    $('#fulltraceswap img').attr('srcset', originalpath);
}
);

//2
$("#fulltracerow .edgtf-iwt-title a[href='#productlifecycle']").hover(
 function(){       

    var path = root+"wp-content/uploads/2018/06/";
    var linkIndex = $(this).attr("href");
    linkIndex = linkIndex.replace('#', '');

    $('#fulltraceswap img').attr('src', path+linkIndex+".jpg");
    $('#fulltraceswap img').attr('srcset', path+linkIndex+".jpg");
},
function(){

    $('#fulltraceswap img').attr('src', originalpath);
    $('#fulltraceswap img').attr('srcset', originalpath);
}
);
```

**EDIT**

I found out what I wanted by using the `a[href^='#']` selecting all links which started with #. 
Backstory - I am using a wordpress plugin called visual composer and in the link options it doesn't allow to add a data attribute...unless I hard coded it. So I wanted a quick workaround. 
Thanks

```
 $("#fulltracerow .edgtf-iwt-title a[href^='#']").hover(

 function(){       

    //we get our current filename and use it for the src
    var path = root+"wp-content/uploads/2018/06/";
    var linkIndex = $(this).attr("href");
    linkIndex = linkIndex.replace('#', '');

    $('#fulltraceswap img').attr('src', path+linkIndex+".jpg");
    $('#fulltraceswap img').attr('srcset', path+linkIndex+".jpg");
},
function(){

    $('#fulltraceswap img').attr('src', originalpath);
    $('#fulltraceswap img').attr('srcset', originalpath);
}
);
```

Comment: can you explain it more what you want to get please? I want help but this is not clear question.

Comment: ah .. if I understand you won't duplicate your code. Its good idea. I would change a[href='#productlifecycle'] to a[data-changeImage] to handle all A tags with data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** You don't need use loop because if you specify right selector, then it apply to all matched elements.

Only what you need is define any global selector with any css class (not id) but I recommend to you use html5 data attribute because it is more flexible than css class.

Advice: 
1) add **data-*** eg. **data-changeImage** for example to all links which use this hover 
action.

```
<a href="#a" data-changeImage>Test1</a>
```

2) change a[href='#aftermarketimage'] to global selector with data attribute like data-changeImage for example and then it works.

```
$("#fulltracerow .edgtf-iwt-title a[data-changeImage]").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
},
function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'green');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/227566/)